# html conditional statement hack sees IE as wrong version when live

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Basically, I'm optimizing a website for the different versions of IE.  I'm using IE9 (verified through the about page of IE).

Locally (with xampp) the website correctly detects that the browser is IE9 and loads the correct css code.  However, when i put the code onto a text server, it sees the browser as IE7.

For tests:

Output I get locally with xmapp

```
According to the conditional comment this is IE
According to the conditional comment this is IE 9
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or higher
According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 6
```

Output I get on the test server:

```
According to the conditional comment this is IE
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower or equal to 7
According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 6
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Edit: What I used to check versions

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or higher<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower or equal to 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
According to the conditional comment this is not IE<br />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: If you hit "F12" on the site, in local and in remote versions, what do you see for "Browser Mode" and for "Document Mode"? Possibly something about your servers is different in terms of content type they are delivering and triggering different modes.

Comment: Local: Browser mode IE9. Document mode IE9 Standards.
Server: Browser mode IE9 compact view. Document mode IE7 standards.  Would there be any fix for this on my end? Or would I have to contact the host?

Comment: `<!--[if IE 6]> 
Die IE6 Die!<br /> 
<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this meta in your head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

And this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/DTD/strict.dtd">
<html>
```